# Enable "Announce the time" with Applescript

Tags: applescript

How do I enable the "Announce the time" option in the Date & Time System Preference using Applescript?

Comment: This will have a much better chance of getting answered over at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via a terminal command: `defaults write`

I managed to dig out the preference file that's being written to when you toggle this setting: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs.plist`. Note that this file may not exist on your computer; it's only created if you've toggled the "Announce the time" checkbox in System Prefs.

The key you're changing the value for is `TimeAnnouncementsEnabled`, which takes a boolean value of `YES` to turn on the announcements and `NO` for off. This key is inside of the dictionary `TimeAnnouncementPrefs` which houses the other settings related to the voice announcements. The terminal command to turn on the time announcements is:

```
defaults write com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs TimeAnnouncementPrefs -dict TimeAnnouncementsEnabled -bool YES
```

To use this in an AppleScript simply do the following (to run a terminal command from AppleScript):

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs TimeAnnouncementPrefs -dict TimeAnnouncementsEnabled -bool YES"
```

That should do it. The other preference keys (voice, custom rate and custom volume) will be reset to their defaults if you use the command as above. If you want to set them to non-default values you'll have to explicitly set them along with the above key value. However, since there are some nested dictionaries you'd probably need to look at using plistbuddy (which isn't installed by default AFAIK). **However, if you only want to set the announcement on/off option, don't worry about it. This will set you up!**

Comment: I'm running 10.7.3 and I can't get this to work. What version(s) have you done this successfully with? Is there a process that you need to killall in order for this to take effect?

Comment: @JasonM This was tested on 10.6.8. I do not use Lion, so cannot test against it. I suspect that the plist setup differs in Lion. You may need to quit System Preferences and reopen it to see the changes, or navigate out of the prefpane and back in.

Comment: I had already tried quitting SysPrefs. That's not enough to effect the change. Per this post http://superuser.com/a/362489/8359 I think you need to chmod and chown. So, I did that and I can see the checkbox change upon restarting SysPrefs. However, I'm not sure the system is actually honoring the checkbox, i.e. even though I found a way to get the checkbox checked, I'm not hearing it announce the time.